# MySQL Workbench restore database rather then import data

Tags: mysql, database-restore

I have a Production MySQL db and a Test MySQL DB. The test db contains a few tables that don't exist in production due to some upgrades. I'd like to copy the production database over the test database which i have done via a self contained dump file but after restoring this to test several times, it looks like it is just importing the data and not removing the extra tables which aren't in production from test.

Is there an overwrite option in MySQL like there is in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You have to drop the DB first then restore.